# Error 2 the system cannot find ...

Tags: python

I can't delete the file using os.remove because some problem with the path.
here is the source code: `http://www.filedropper.com/install_5` 
or : `http://pastebin.com/L0na3XPm`

i would be happy if someone can help me , thank you all
love

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please don't link to code on an external site.

Answer (score 2):

I see the line:

```
rmv=dst+"\\insatll.py"
```

Is this supposed to be "\\install.py" ?

Comment: Yes. I want to remove this file.

Comment: Is 'insatll' a typo?

Comment: What thats mean typo ?

Comment: Is the file called `install.py` or `insatll.py`?

Comment: install.py the file name .

Comment: Okay then you need to change the line: `rmv=dst+"\\insatll.py"` to `rmv=dst+"\\install.py"`. The `t` and the `a` are mixed up.

Comment: I have another problem. uac problem , access is denied. i can't run the file from the cmd for some reason .. there is any way to give the file administrator permission with run cmd as administrator?

Comment: try the `elevate` command. Run `elevate <command>` to run as administrator.

Comment: can you give me an example please ?

Comment: `elevate python install.py`

Comment: whrere to run the elevate? in the cmd? "elevate is not recognized as an internal command"

Comment: Yes in command prompt. If `elevate` is not available. Try `runas /user:<adminusername> python install.py` I am finding these solutions online I am not a PC user.